# Cant Start Job With Ubuntu Upstart

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, init, upstart, init.d

I have heard that Ubuntu upstart is the way to go for dameonization.  So I tried this:

First I added an init script in /etc/init/application.conf:

```
description "Application"
author "David Williams"
env JAVA_OPTS="-server -verbose:gc -Xms1G -Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
respawn
exec su nobody -s /bin/sh -c 'exec /usr/java/default/bin/java -jar /home/ec2-user/Application.one-jar.jar'
```

But then this fails:

```
$ start application
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.123" (uid=500 pid=8161 comm="start) 
interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 
destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init))
```

If I remember correctly I also need a file in /etc/init.d but I am finding the Upstart docs to be kindof opaque since I'm also not a sysadmin.  What should I do to get this running like an upstart script?

```
$ start application
$ stop application
$ restart application
```

[UPDATE]

I needed to use sudo

```
$ sudo start application
application start/running, process 8399
```

But that process doesnt list under ps aux

```
$ sudo ps aux | grep 8339
ec2-user  8424  0.0  0.0 103244   820 pts/0    S+   19:41   0:00 grep 8339
```

Stuck here.

Comment: Does it have 755 permissions and belongs to root?

Comment: Whats it in this case?  The application.conf?  If so, then no it does not.  It is owned by root but is -rw-r--r--.

Comment: but this is in /etc/init, do you mean something in init.d?  I tried moving it to init.d but this was the result `$ start application
start: Unknown job: application`